# Is there a starter theme? If so what is it?

Tags: 10

Does Drupal have a starter theme? If so what is it?

If this is Stark<sup>[1](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/core/themes/stark), [2](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/themes/stark-theme), [3](https://www.drupal.org/project/stark)</sup>, then [I don't think it's practically **the** starter theme of Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/stark).

Comment: Why this question again? It's subjective. The starter theme for *you* is whatever one best suits your needs. You can use stark. You can use Olivero. You can use any of the hundreds of contributed themes.

Comment: The documentation for the Stark theme is clear: It says *The Stark theme is **provided for demonstration purposes*** and *Users **should not use it as a base theme** as future core updates may break your theme*. How can it be a starter theme if users should not use it?

Comment: Even better, this should be a discussion to have in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers).

Answer (score 3):

The most popular are (counting only Drupal 8/9/10):

- 58777 [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap)
- 45522 [Stable](https://www.drupal.org/project/stable)
- 33665 [Barrio Bootstrap 5 Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio)

The contrib Stable is used to upgrade Drupal 8/9 sites, it shouldn't be used for new Drupal 10 projects. There is no replacement for Stable, put `base theme: false` in your theme info file if you only want to depend on core styling or use the new https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-themes/starterkit-theme